# C# Secondary monitor resolution is not proper

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, screen-resolution, multiple-monitors

I have Full HD TV connected to my pc through HDMI,and am trying to get the resolution of this extended display like this.

```
if (System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1)
{                              
    Settings.TVWidth = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds.Width;
    Settings.TVHeight = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds.Height;
}
```

When I change resolution of this extended display in my graphic control properties, the values what am getting is same as what I set till 1280 X 720.
Anything higher resolution like 1920 X 1080p, still it gives 1280 X 720.

Is there any other methods to get the actual resolution of this extended display?

Note:My pc resolution is 1366 X 768

Comment: I suspect it will relate to DPI-Awareness here - your application is being lied to because it will be stretched to fit *as if* it's sitting on a 1280x720 screen.

Comment: You need at least Windows 8.1 to take advantage of the per-monitor DPI feature.  And you have to tell Windows that you know how to deal with it, pinvoke SetProcessDpiAwareness() or edit the manifest.

Comment: @HansPassant I have Windows 10..and what changes needs to be done in manifest

Comment: Google "per-monitor dpi manifest", take the first hit.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for pointing towrds per monitor DPI feature. Now its working elegantly.